# Edit JSON data by the use of PHP script

Tags: php, mysql, json

This is my JSON code which I want to run through a PHP Script:

```
{"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]},{"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]}
```

I want JSON data like.

```
{"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]}
{"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]}
```

Means each source start with new line and no comma between them.
Here is my php code which gives the JSON file.

```
$p=0;
array_push($result_comments,$result);
$fp = fopen($p.'_results.json', 'w');
fwrite($fp, json_encode(utf8ize($result_comments)));
fclose($fp);
 $p ++;
```

This is the function

```
function utf8ize($d) {
    if (is_array($d)) {
        foreach ($d as $k => $v) {
            $d[$k] = utf8ize($v);
        }
    } else if (is_string ($d)) {
        return utf8_encode($d);
    }
    return $d;
}
```

Please suggest can i get desired json data by the modification on php script.Or I have to remove it manually.

Comment: Your wanted json is **invalid**

Comment: 'this is my json ... which I get to run' -> I don't think you can execute json.  Anyway, you want a different output I gues. Did you look up pretty printers ? I'm sure there are plenty of them for Json.

Comment: @u_mulder: Yes I know this is a invalid JSON.But the requirement is that each line will be a valid JSON not whole file

Comment: Use this, for example, for validating your JSON: http://jsonlint.com/ because you won't be able to work with invalid JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like the following. Json encode each row and add it to `$result_comments` array. At the end implode this array with line breaks and write it the file: (`$data` is you given json as php array)

```
$data = array (
    0 =>
        array (
            'source' => 'URl',
            'title' => 'New title',
            'created' => 'date',
            'id' => 'xxxxx',
            'comments' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'id' => 'xxxx',
                            'imported_display_name' => 'xxxx',
                            'body_html' => 'xxxxx',
                            'imported_email' => 'xxxxx',
                            'parent_id' => 'xxxx',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
    1 =>
        array (
            'source' => 'URl',
            'title' => 'New title',
            'created' => 'date',
            'id' => 'xxxxx',
            'comments' =>
                array (
                    0 =>
                        array (
                            'id' => 'xxxx',
                            'imported_display_name' => 'xxxx',
                            'body_html' => 'xxxxx',
                            'imported_email' => 'xxxxx',
                            'parent_id' => 'xxxx',
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);

$result_comments = array();
foreach($data as $result){
    $result_comments[] = json_encode(utf8ize($result));
}
file_put_contents('results.json',implode(PHP_EOL,$result_comments));
// result.json
// {"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]}
// {"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]}
```

Comment: It gives the destroyed structure like this: "URl",:"New title",,:"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]},{"source":"URl","title":"New title","created":"date","id":"xxxxx","comments":[{"id":"xxxx","imported_display_name":"xxxx","body_html":"xxxxx","imported_email":"xxxxx","parent_id":"xxxx"}]}.     Means it remove all the index name and and starting curly braces are not at the starting

Comment: i expected that `$data` is like the array i added to the answer now. This gives me the file you ask for

Comment: Thank you so much you save my multiple days and efforts.